# insert values in table with out some columns that may change time to time

Tags: oracle, plsql

insert values in table contain 5 column some times insert with 3 columns and some time all 5 columns data come from front end is not constant dependent upon user insert in front end?

if 4 column value no value for one column and 3 column and 2 column no value also we need to insert value in the table ?

Comment: are these field allowed null values in database..???

Comment: yes insted of any non valued column we store null also..

Comment: It seems that your problem more on frontend side than in Oracle database. Can you please update your question and show more details about frontend (development tools and desired format of call)?

Comment: front end is android ..

Answer (score 1):

Specify all the columns in your insert statement. The parameters to which you pass null values will be stored as null in the table. There's no need to change your insert statement based on which parameters have non-null values.

```
create or replace procedure insert_stuff(i_input1 in varchar2, i_input2 in 
varchar2... i_input10 in varchar2)is
    begin
    insert into my_table (col1, col2... col10) values(i_input1, i_input2... 
i_input10);
end;
```

Comment: +1 @Zesty - solid advice, meaning I was thinking the same :) There's no need to complicate this if it's just about inserting rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for query, then use syntax:

```
insert into tablename(columnlist seperated by comma) values (values list seperated by comma).
```

For Example:

```
insert into TableName(column1_name,column2_name) values(val1,val2);
```

Comment: user give value for 2 column some times 3 column and it may change accordingly so it come many possibility so that much insert query not posiable

Comment: Ok, so in that case you can execute different query based on the columns by the help of if..else inside an stored proc

Comment: ok is ther any comands or technical syntax like posiable .only using if else

Comment: one alternative is to use dynamic query. Based on columns, first contruct your dynamic query and then open an output cursor for that dynamic query to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use your stored procedure in this way:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION testFunction
(
  field1 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  field2 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  field3 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
 // your insert query goes here.
END;
```

If the value for any of the field is not assigned then, it will automatically assign the default value i.e. NULL. Just have a check and i hope it will help you.:)